# Details about Google+ API SHA-1 hash code

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-api, google-plus-signin

I am using **Google plus API** in my android application. To use Google android API **SHA-1 code** is needed to use the API. I want to know why this SHA-1 hash code is asked by Google?
I also want to know whether this hash code is machine specific or sdk specific or depends on something else.

I am asking because I am facing some problem in API authentication logcat shows :

> BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me

I believe answers to these questions will help in debugging.

Comment: Its because google provide daily limited read and write data. If you need extra then you need to buy that.

Comment: I want to know how keytool is generating this key what information it takes as input?

Comment: Pretty sure this is backend and won't be disclosed to the public. In any case, if I were you, I would post a question about why you can't auth, and what you're currently doing to authenticate. This might get some more answers than your current question, which will boil down to "because the backend engineers decided it would be this way"

Comment: Thanks Patrice! Actually I already posted a question about that and got my mistake resolved. My code is not giving this error now

Comment: Happy to hear it's fixed :). Cheers and happy coding!